# Black spots on cups from Cracker Barrel

Tags: food-safety

I have a favorite cup made in China that has developed black spots inside the bottom.  I'm worried about lead -- should I stop using it? It isn't crazing but seems to be a failed glaze. I bought 6 of these from Cracker Barrel restaurant a year ago as part of a set with serving dishes signed by Susan Winget -- the Nature Walk series for Cracker Barrel Old Country Store. The add picture function isn't working but I can send pictures to anyone who's interested.

Comment: I suspect cannot add a picture is a reputation thing.

Comment: If I remember right, you only need 10 rep to post an image, so you should be able to add it now. If not, you can upload it somewhere and add the url, and we can edit it directly into your post for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy lead testing kits online or a hardware store. (You want test swabs, not a water-testing kit). Expect to pay $10–20.